# Bind highcharts chart to another series

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to change chart series and redraw it.

```
var newSeries = [1,2,3,4,5]

 $('#miniChart').highcharts(
 {
   series:[data:newSeries]
 }
)
```

Doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You syntax isn't correct.  Should be:

```
var newSeries = [1,2,3,4,5];
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: newSeries
    }]
});
```

If you already have a chart, though, and just want to change the data of a series, you'd be better off using the `setData` [method of the series object](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData).

```
var newSeries = [1,2,3,4,5];
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
chart.series[0].setData(newSeries);
```

Here's a [fiddle showing both ways](http://jsfiddle.net/2qdG4/1/).